# How could WebLogic listen multiple protocols on the same port?

Tags: networking, weblogic, protocols

When WebLogic is started, the info log mentions the port *xxxx* listens for http, iiop, t3 and ldap protocols.

```
<Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
```

How could one port be bound to multiple protocols? Does WebLogic implement some sort of socket multiplexer, which speaks all the protocols and delegates to the correct handler? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ports are associated to the TCP/IP protocol (transport layer), whereas http, iiop, ecc.. are application layers protocols. Nothing odd, be sure! In weblogic ports are associated to managed servers, admin server and so on, not to specific application layer protocols.